# What is the difference between substracting and adding numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am receving JSON from server and have to add or substract some numbers, but it does not work for adding, but for substracting it does.
Any idea why?

```js
data = {
  point: {
    x: '4.0',
    y: '10.0'
  }
}

startX = 10;
startY = 5;

newX= startX + data.point.x;
newY= startY - data.point.y;

console.log(newX, newY)
```

Comment: you're concatenating a string with a number, not adding a number with a number.

Comment: The `+` operator is used for both addition for `Number` types and concatenation for `String` types.

Comment: try converting string to numbers before `parseInt()`

Comment: Avoid using `parseFloat()` and `parseInt()`, use `Number()` instead. or do `+"5"` or `"5"-0`. These are more stricts operations and won't convert a string like `"5a"` to `5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the string to a number, because strings a possible to add, which means concat. By taking `-` both operands are converted to number.

```js
var data = { point: { x: '4.0', y: '10.0' } },
startX = 10,
startY = 5,
newX = startX + +data.point.x,
newY = startY - +data.point.y;

console.log(newX, newY)
```

Comment: The `+` cast hack is cute but obscure. Recommend [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)/[`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for clarity.

Comment: [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) is not a hack, but a language feature.

Comment: unary plus is often used and is considered strongly semantic as casting boolean with double `!!`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're numbers from the JSON are treated as strings not numbers.
You need to convert them to numbers (integer or float) first.

```
newX = startX + parseFloat(data.point.x);
newY = startY - parseFloat(data.point.y);
```

Comment: Since JS only has a single numeric format, you'd only convert to that, not to integer or a float. The `parseInt` function just stops parsing when it encounters a non-integer character and `.` is one. That is a valid character for `parseFloat`, though. Point is, they don't produce two different types, but the same one. The value can be different if you use them on `"3.14"` but parsing the string `"4.0"` will produce the *exact* same value with either function.

Comment: While that's true of course I assume the OP might want to use decimals since he's using floats in the JSON data, so I can't reccommend using parseInt() for conversion. parseFloat() will handle both cases just fine.